# Adding a C Wire to a wall mounted gas heater for a WiFI Thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have a typical 2 wire thermostat for a wall mounted propane heater. I want to install a wifi honeywell thermostat.  The thermostat is right next to the heater so running a third wire is no problem I just don't have a clue where the wire taps into the homeywell gas control valve see pics below The red and white are the 2 wires to the thermostat

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might not even be a 24v system and might take more work to get a wifi thermostat working.  Unless you know how to measure voltages and wire up a relay, this might not be something you can DIY.

Answer (score 1):

the "WHT" wire that goes from the 24V transformer to the gas valve is the C wire, tap into that.

looking at the picture of the valve it looks like the two terminals on the front of the valve (near the knob) are boith the same piece of metal, so C will be be the stripy wire on the side near the gas plumbing.

Comment: It should be the wire connected to the TR (transformer) terminal on the gas valve

Comment: yes, one of those wires, not the other one.

Comment: The three gas valve terminals are uniquely labeled (TR, TH, TH/TR)

Comment: So the hardware doesn't match the wiring digram where the four terminal are tow labeled th and two tr?

Comment: I could be reading the diagram wrong all the same

Comment: looking at the picture of the valve  it lookls like the two terminals on the front of the valve (near the knob) are both the same piece of metal, so that will be R and C will be  be the stripy wire on the side near the gas plumbing.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response it’s much appreciated the last question is what gage wire should I run for C ?

Comment: use the same same as the R and W,  cut back some of that brown stuff there may be one inside there already.

Comment: @ejvette instead of writing a "thanks" comment, please up vote the answer to show your appreciation. You'll learn that if you take the [tour].